# PHP preg match - regular expression with float value

Tags: php, regex, floating-point, preg-match

have this string:

```
$var = "30.5x120.8 (test desc here)";
```

I need to get out 30.5 and 120.8 with a regular expression.. any help?? Thx

Comment: If your regex questions are recurring, check out http://regular-expressions.info/ to learn the syntax, or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there-anything-like-regexbuddy-in-the-open-source-world for tools to craft them.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
preg_match_all('~\d+(?:\.\d+)?~', $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches[0]);
```

Comment: @Ste: What about `30.5x.2`? Is that a thing you want to support?

Comment: @Alix Axel: I don't think, but is possible replace .2 with 0.2 ?

Comment: @Ste: Sure you can replace it. Just do `$string = preg_replace('(?<!\d)\.\d+', '0$0', $string);` before you run the code above.

Answer (score 8):

```
$var = "30x120 (test desc here)";
 
preg_match_all('/^(\d+)x(\d+)/', $var, $matches);
 
var_dump($matches)
```

[Ideone](http://ideone.com/FOhTa).

#### Output

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "30x120"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "30"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "120"
  }
}
```

---

### Update

> also work for 17.5x17.5 ?

Here is one which will...

```
/^(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)x(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)/
```

[Ideone](http://ideone.com/WeJMQ).

Comment: I think `preg_match()` would make more sense (and make the output array easier to parse) than `preg_match_all()` as there's only one occurence of the pattern in the subject string.

Answer (score 2):

```
preg_match('/^(\d+)x(\d+)/', '30x120 (test desc here)', $result);
```

and use `$result[1]` and `$result[2]`

Comment: meh - posted near identically at the same time as @Kevin

Comment: It's often a question of seconds :p

Answer (score 1):

The following should do the trick: `/^(\d+)x(\d+)/`

[Running code](http://www.ideone.com/syxIf)